# How can I make this function less messy?

Tags: java, actionevent

I want to make this function less messy, I don't want individual if statements for every button but I can't figure out a correct solution. Anyone want to help?

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 ) {

if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[0]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[0]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[1]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[1]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[2]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[2]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[3]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[3]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[4]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[4]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[5]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[5]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[6]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[6]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[7]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[7]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[8]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[8]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[9]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[9]);
}
if(arg0.getSource()==buttons[10]){
  txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[10]);
}

}
```

What can I use to make this function shorter? A HashMap? For loop? Please assist. I want to have 20 buttons in total, I have only posted half of the function as the rest is redundant. bText is a string array with all necessary buttons for a calculator program. I.E 1, 2, 3, C, CE, etc.

Comment: You have a common index in the condition (if) and action (then).  Use a loop.

Comment: What is bText? Is this a calculator? Please tell the details of the problem.

Comment: You'd probably create the buttons in a for loop and give each one its own ActionListener on creation, something like `buttons[i].addActionListener(e -> txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[i]));`, but again, we have no idea what `bText` is or what it holds or what this does. .... Please ask a more complete question, else it is not too helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know about Java but in a similar language you could do something like this,

```
   for (int i = 0; i < button.length; i++)
   {
       if(arg0.getSource() == buttons[i])
       {
          txField.setText(txField.getText() + bText[i]);
          break;
       }
   }
```